# How can i get the hours that are between a certain fringe oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, hour

I need to get the hours that are between a time slot.
My code is as follows, but I do not get exactly the results I need.
Since it does not show me all the results that are in that range

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date_quote,'dd/MM/yy'),'dd/MM/yy') date_quote,
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(start_time,'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') start_time,
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(end_time,'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') end_time

        FROM
            quote
        WHERE 
                start_time < to_timestamp('1970/01/01 11:30:00','yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')
            and
                end_time > to_timestamp('1970/01/01 11:15:00','yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS') 

        AND
            date_quote= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2017-05-01','yyyy-MM-dd'),'dd/MM/yyyy')
    )
ORDER BY
    date_quote ASC,
    start_time ASC;
```

I have also tried with >= <= but it does not give me the expected result either

Comment: What datatype are `start_time` and `end_time`? What does the data look like? You need to show us some sample data so we can see the difference between what you have now and what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to calculate the total time taken to close a task.
 so you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(end_time,'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(start_time,'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') total_time_taken
  FROM quote
  WHERE start_time < to_timestamp('1970/01/01 11:30:00','yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')
  AND end_time     > to_timestamp('1970/01/01 11:15:00','yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')--- kinldy check your condition as end time is less then task start time
  AND date_quote   = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2017-05-01','yyyy-MM-dd'),'dd/MM/yyyy')
  )
ORDER BY date_quote ASC,
  start_time ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `date_quote`, `fecha_apunte_fh`, `start_time` and `end_time` are all `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` columns and that `start_time` is before `end_time` then

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         TRUNC( date_quote ) date_quote,
         start_time,
         end_time
  FROM   quote
  WHERE  start_time > TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 11:15:00'
  AND    end_time   < TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 11:30:00'
  AND    fecha_apunte_fh = DATE '2017-05-01'
)
ORDER BY
    date_quote ASC,
    start_time ASC;
```